# Write out to a file a dictionary of objects and string

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, object

Trying to run through a dictionary  string and write the contents to file that should be easy on the eyes.

```
 Dictionary<CArray, string> dictCArray = new Dictionary<CArray, string>();
            DateTime dtmPad = DateTime.Today;
            for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                CArray caobject = new CArray();
                dictCArray.Add(caobject, s1[i, 0]);
                for (int x = 0; x < idatelength; x++)
                {
                    caobject.dtmday = dtmPad.AddDays(x);
                    caobject.s2 = Create(ilength);
                    caobject.s3 = s1[i, 1];
                    caobject.dictC.Add(caobject.dtmday, caobject.s2);
                }
            }
```

Where CArray is a class with two strings and a dictionary that contains a datetime and a string.

```
class CArray
{
    public DateTime dtmday;
    public string s2;
    public string s3;
    public Dictionary<DateTime, string> dictC = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
}
```

I need a way to run through it and output it to a file, and also have the ability to read that file back into the same format.  I am just stumped on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [serialization.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) All you'll need to do is implement two functions for your custom class.

A note: This won't make easy-to-read files, but it will work well for saving/loading from files.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the varying types in a linear fashion and make use of the `BinaryWriter`. To read the data back in you would use the `BinaryReader`.

You could write out  out the `DateTime` as a long via the `Ticks` property.

Here is a [brief sample](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/bba59c2f-37aa-4b84-93e3-5068d0c25d6c/) on writing/reading with the `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` and a `Dictionary<K,V>`